# static routes not working for me

Tags: router, static-routes

I have three routers connected like this:

*Internet* ------- (WAN) **RouterA** (LAN) ------(LAN) **RouterB** (WAN) ---- *(VPN)* ---- (WAN) **RouterC**

- RouterA: RV042G; LAN: 192.168.100.100 /24

  *static route for RouterA: destination 192.168.102.0/24 default gateway: 192.168.100.101 (all traffic to routerC should be redirected to routerB)*
- RouterB: RV180; LAN: 192.168.100.101 /24 WAN: 192.168.101.1/24

  *I did not define a static route on this router. There is only one VPN connection defined to routerC*
- RouterC: RV180; LAN: 192.168.102.101 /24 WAN: 192.168.101.2/24

  *I did not define a static route on this router. There is only one VPN connection defined to routerB*
- Local DNS ( 192.168.100.200) is installed behind RouterA.

Computers behind routerA have as gateway it's IP (192.168.100.100) and 192.168.100.200 as DNS ( the one behind routerA).

Computers behind routerC have as gateway it's IP (192.168.102.101) and 192.168.100.200 as DNS ( the one behind routerA).

In this configuration all computers from both networks can access ( ping, file transfer) each other ( by IP or by name). Compuers behind routerA have Internet access ( ping, web page browsing ).

I would like to give Internet acces for users connected to routerC but no matter what I have tried I can not make that to work.

I thought that the above route will solve my problem but computers behind routerC still have no Internet access.  If I ping yahoo.com ( by name or IP) from behind routerC I get no response; from routerA everything it is working well.

I suppose that I have to define a new static route but indifferent of what I have tried ( from google, tips from friends) I do not get the desired result.

Do you have any tips for me?

Thank you!

Comment: Your question lacks the kind of detail we would need in order to provide an answer, such as; What make/model routers are you using? What do the routing tables on each router look like? What are the ip address settings for clients on each network? Etc., etc. Think about your question. How could we provide an answer based on what you've told us?

Comment: read http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html and try asking again

Comment: I have added new information to the initial question. Thank you!

Comment: `1.` Does Router C have a route to Router A through Router B? `2.` Does Router A have a default gateway defined toward the WAN interface? Do all of the clients have an appropriate default gateway set?

Comment: On routerC I have not defined any static route. There is only one VPN connection to routerB. Yes all computer have settings for gateway and DNS. Except Internet access everything elese works well. I have added to the initial question the computer settings too. Thank you!